# Array Map multidimensional, get values from 3 array Java

Tags: arrays, json, loops, multidimensional-array

Let say I have 3 arrays,

```
compCD = ["909", "908", "080", "901"];
contNO = ["09999", "08888", "00777", "00666"];
pomNum = ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"];
```

How can I insert into **jsonMap** each separated Values like

```
[
  {
    "compCD" = "909",
    "contNO" = "09999",
    "pomNum" = "A01"
  },{
    "compCD" = "908",
    "contNO" = "08888",
    "pomNum" = "A02"
  }
]
```

we can assume that each array size is the same. The first of each array will bi insert first to map.

How we can solve those with **minimum loop**.

Comment: I'm assuming you are showing values, not assigning.
Values seem to be `String`s, so surround with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var compCD = ["909", "908", "080", "901"];
var contNO = ["09999", "08888", "00777", "00666"];
var pomNum = ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"];

var jsonMap=[];
for(var i=0; i<compCD.length; i++) {
  jsonMap.push(
    {compCD:compCD[i], contNO:contNO[i], pomNum:pomNum[i]}
  );
};

console.log(jsonMap);
```

```js
var compCD = ["909", "908", "080", "901"];
var contNO = ["09999", "08888", "00777", "00666"];
var pomNum = ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"];

var jsonMap=compCD.map(
  (currentValue, index)=>[currentValue, contNO[index], pomNum[index]]
);

console.log(jsonMap);
```

Comment: You are welcome!
Yes, it is javascript - sorry if that's not what you wanted. - did you have any language in mind?  Each language has a different syntax to do this...

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation - that's why I've assumed JavaScript.

Comment: Well that works in JavaScript, currently i need in java, actually I need in java code, cause right now i'm working used java Code. That's good answer actually, Nice

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer.
I've added the `Array.prototype.map()` option.
More about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map